# Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080 (deploying Jenkins in google kubernetes cloud)

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have followed all the steps in [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine-tutorial)

and verified that they all completed successfully.

But when I get to the last part where I preview the application on port 8080 I get the error:

```
Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 8080.
Ensure your server is listening on port 8080 and try again.
```

I have also tried to change the port to 8084 but same result.

Any suggestions on how to debug/fix this?

Below the result of some of the last commands that I executed on my local machine using the locally installed gcloud client:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cd-jenkins-7c786475dd-bz7kj   1/1       Running   0          2m

$ printf $(kubectl get secret cd-jenkins -o jsonpath="{.data.jenkins-admin-password}" | base64 --decode);echo
********
$ export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -l "component=cd-jenkins-master" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
$ kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:8080 >> /dev/null &
[1] 24685
$ echo $POD_NAME
cd-jenkins-7c786475dd-bz7kj
```

Comment: Can you check if port forwarding is still running on your cloud shell?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes do you use in your cluster? Where are you trying to connect to the Jenkins from?

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually did?  You are talking about "last commands that I executed on my *local* machine using the *locally* installed gcloud client" (emphasis mine), but the tutorial is not written to be run locally - you are supposed to be doing the whole tutorial in Cloud Shell?  Or is that what you mean by 'local'?

Answer (score 0):

**Accessing Jenkins through your local machine:**

You can run all `kubectl` commands within your local machine, but if you run `kubectl port-forwarding` in your local machine you will have to access the Jenkins page through this address http://localhost:8080/.

**Accessing Jenkins through Google Cloud Console:**

In the Google Cloud Console, on the top right menu just click on the following icon `>_` (Activate Cloud Shell) then run the port-forwarding command:

```
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master" -l "app.kubernetes.io/instance=cd" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:8080 >> /dev/null &
```

Now if you click on the icon `Web preview` -> `Preview on port 8080` you should see the login page.

Just remember that the port is only forwarded while the `kubectl` process is running.